# how do you get a pre-loader html code to work in reactjs App?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Below is the html code:

```
<div id="loader" class="show">
<div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

It is pasted in the index.html default js component of a react app (web app) and the problem is that app just loads and loads, it never reveals the contents of the page.

Comment: Do you have root component for react there? `<div id="root"></div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you removed the div with id="root" because react render component inside that div. So the solution is you can place it inside id="root" div in your index.html file and it will show on loading and disappear whenever your first react component renders.

```
<div id="root">
   <div id="loader" class="show">
      <div class="loader"></div>
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if you think it was the solution to your problem. Happy coding :-)